# Change my current working directory in Python to my external hard drive.

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on a project which requires me to process large amounts of uncompressed video data so I need to store all the data on my external hard drive. So far I have obtained the cwd with:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

And I know how to change the directory with the following command:

```
path='E:\College\Project\3dlife-gc-2013-dataset-hhi\3dlife-gc-2013-dataset-hhi'
os.chdir(path)
```

This command does not allow me to change the cwd as I desire. I suspect that my path is not formatted correctly. Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.

```
>>> 'E:\College\Project\3dlife-gc-2013-dataset-hhi\3dlife-gc-2013-dataset-hhi'
'E:\\College\\Project\x03dlife-gc-2013-dataset-hhi\x03dlife-gc-2013-dataset-hhi'
```

Double the backslashes, use forward slashes, or use a raw string.